# Active Delimiters to get correct delimiter size

Tags: math-mode, delimiters, catcodes

I once read in "Die Texnische Komödie 1/2011" that it is possible to make the round delimiters `()` active, so you don´t need do use `\left(\right)` any more. The code is:

```
\makeatletter
\def\resetMathstrut@{%
    \setbox\z@\hbox{%
        \mathchardef\@tempa\mathcode`\[\relax
        \def\@tempb##1"##2##3{\the\textfont"##3\char"}%
        \expandafter\@tempb\meaning\@tempa \relax
    }%
    \ht\Mathstrutbox@\ht\z@ \dp\Mathstrutbox@\dp\z@}
\makeatother
\begingroup
\catcode`(\active \xdef({\left\string(}
\catcode`)\active \xdef){\right\string)}
\endgroup
\mathcode`(="8000 \mathcode`)="8000
\setlength\delimitershortfall{-1pt}

\makeatletter
\catcode`\_\active
\def_#1{\sb{\operator@font#1}}
\makeatother
```

Don´t ask me details about, I am not into them.

Now I wonder if it is possible to change `[]` and maybe `\{\}` the  same way, so that you  don´t need to use `\left...\right...` any more for "normal" delimiters.

Thanks for your help!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\resetMathstrut@{%
    \setbox\z@\hbox{%
        \mathchardef\@tempa\mathcode`\[\relax
        \def\@tempb##1"##2##3{\the\textfont"##3\char"}%
        \expandafter\@tempb\meaning\@tempa \relax
    }%
    \ht\Mathstrutbox@\ht\z@ \dp\Mathstrutbox@\dp\z@}
\makeatother
\begingroup
\catcode`(\active \xdef({\left\string(}
\catcode`)\active \xdef){\right\string)}
\endgroup
\mathcode`(="8000 \mathcode`)="8000
\setlength\delimitershortfall{-1pt}

\makeatletter
\catcode`\_\active
\def_#1{\sb{\operator@font#1}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        ((((a+b)(a-b))))=a^2-b^2
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: generally it's not recommended to over-use `\left` and `\right` you often get better spacing if you choose the size explictly (`\big(` etc.

Comment: In addition to redefining `(` the code shown makes all subscripts use an upright font??

Comment: Yeah^^ I wanted this feature too, but it is not needed in the code here. You see, I am not into it.

Comment: It is needed to use it with the amsmath package. Why is written in the "TeXnische Komödie"

Comment: I just wanted to comment to thank you because your post gave me what I needed to finally answer [my own question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/565217/54601) satisfactorily (compared with David's answer that just says it's not a good idea). =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just repeat the definitions used for `(` with `[` but really you should not do this, the setting with `\delimitershortfall` and over use of `\left` and `\right` is producing a really poor setting with over large delimiters and over large horizontal space. Automating this layout ought to be a non-aim!

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\edef\zzz{\the\mathcode`\[}
\def\resetMathstrut@{%
    \setbox\z@\hbox{%
        \mathchardef\@tempa\zzz\relax
        \def\@tempb##1"##2##3{\the\textfont"##3\char"}%
        \expandafter\@tempb\meaning\@tempa \relax
    }%
    \ht\Mathstrutbox@\ht\z@ \dp\Mathstrutbox@\dp\z@}
\makeatother



\begingroup
\catcode`(\active \xdef({\left\string(}
\catcode`)\active \xdef){\right\string)}
\endgroup
\mathcode`(="8000 \mathcode`)="8000

\begingroup
\catcode`[\active \xdef[{\left\string[}
\catcode`]\active \xdef]{\right\string]}
\endgroup
\mathcode`[="8000 \mathcode`]="8000


\setlength\delimitershortfall{-1pt}





\begin{document}

    \begin{align}
        ((((a+b)(a-b))))=a^2-b^2 \\ \relax
        [[[[a+b][a-b]]]]=a^2-b^2
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, so it is possible, but makes no sense. Thank you.