# Automatically increase spacing inside brackets

Tags: math-mode, spacing, brackets

I find LaTeX's automatic spacing for a lot of common mathematical expressions to be extremely ugly, especially with respect to brackets. For example:

`$f(x+a)$` and `$\mathbf{P}(x=a)$` both have "x" and "a" closer to the bracket than to the equal-sign.

To mitigate that, I would like to increase the spacing after `(` and before `)` **automatically** in all math. How can I do that? (I definitely do not want to manually insert `\,` all over to obtain a better spacing.) Unfortunately, I am not familiar enough with TeX to know how to meddle with primitives like brackets.

Comment: tex is not expecting = to be used in a function argument so it gets wide spacing for a top level relation, rather than change the spacing for brackets (which is hard as tex inserts no space there, so no standard parameter that you can change) I would use a tighter = and  use `(x{=}a)`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I know there are all sorts of tricks for eliminating spaces or adding spaces **manually**, but it makes no sense to do that for **every** instance of the first example (which does not use "=").

Comment: And yes I know that there is no simple parameter that can be changed, which is why I am asking this question. I know that it will require a low-level redefinition of brackets.

Comment: well as I say tex has no parameter to control the space around ( and ) so you would need to modify the font metrics (not so easy) or make ( and ) active and act as macros to add the space (hard and very fragile if you do not want to break `\left(` ) so it would almost certainly break in real documents. But apart from that I think reducing the space around = is the more correct change than increasing the space around ()

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Did you read my question and first comment carefully? I said the problem applies to all binary operations as well, not just the equal-sign. Are you saying I should decrease *all* the muskips to the minimum? That doesn't make sense. As I said, I do not want to do it manually.

Comment: well actually you only commented on the = sign, although you gave a fragment using a + as well, but anyway; OK it's not as if I downvoted the question, the the question itself is reasonable, it's just that I expect that it has no reasonable answer using tex (using luatex you may have a better chance) defining `)` to add space before in a way that does not break `\right)`  would be hard (if I could think of a way at all) and would almost certainly not work in real documents, so the comments are just a warning that no answer coming from me, and I would be surprised if you get one at all.

Comment: I don't see why it doesn't make sense to define a command such as `\apply{f}{x+a}` and `\apply{\mathbf{P}}{x=a}`  then the `\apply` macro` can do `\mathop{{}#1}\left(\,#2\,\right)` if that is what you want.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: If you have an explanation as to why what I'm asking for would be hard or impossible, it would be helpful, because I do not understand what is so difficult about it. I have played with hacking `\left` and `\right` before and have used my hacks for years with no trouble, so presumably it should be possible to hack `(` and `)` as well, but that is really too low-level for me. Regarding your last comment, it's too cumbersome. When my document is full of functions, I don't want to spend half my time typing macros, if there is a once-for-all solution (no matter how hacky).

Comment: as I say I can not think of an answer that does what you want. So I can't really give a detailed breakdown of why it is hard:-) You are just asking for a feature that TeX doesn't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to automatically increases spacing after `(` and before `)`. For those modified by `\left` and `right` it is easy:

```
\renewcommand\left[1]{\mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\ifx#1(\originalleft(\,\else\originalleft#1\fi}
\renewcommand\right[1]{\aftergroup\egroup\ifx#1)\,\originalright)\else\originalright#1\fi}
```

For ordinary brackets, we need to use [a trick to make them active](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204663). Applied here we get:

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`(\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\oldlbrac\,}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathchardef\oldlbrac=\mathcode`(\mathcode`(="8000}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`)\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\,\oldrbrac}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathchardef\oldrbrac=\mathcode`)\mathcode`)="8000}
\makeatletter
\def\resetMathstrut@{%
    \setbox\z@\hbox{%
        \mathchardef\@tempa\mathcode`\[\relax
        \def\@tempb##1"##2##3{\the\textfont"##3\char"}%
        \expandafter\@tempb\meaning\@tempa \relax
    }%
    \ht\Mathstrutbox@\ht\z@ \dp\Mathstrutbox@\dp\z@}
\makeatother
```

Here is complete working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newlength\bracskip\setlength{\bracskip}{.04em plus .04em minus .02em}
\newcommand\bracspace{\hspace{\bracskip}}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`(\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\oldlbrac\bracspace}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathchardef\oldlbrac=\mathcode`(\mathcode`(="8000}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`)\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\bracspace\oldrbrac}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathchardef\oldrbrac=\mathcode`)\mathcode`)="8000}
\let\originalleft\left
\let\originalright\right
\renewcommand\left[1]{\mathopen{}\mathclose\bgroup\ifx#1(\originalleft(\,\else\originalleft#1\fi}
\renewcommand\right[1]{\aftergroup\egroup\ifx#1)\,\originalright)\else\originalright#1\fi}
\makeatletter
\def\resetMathstrut@{%
    \setbox\z@\hbox{%
        \mathchardef\@tempa\mathcode`\[\relax
        \def\@tempb##1"##2##3{\the\textfont"##3\char"}%
        \expandafter\@tempb\meaning\@tempa \relax
    }%
    \ht\Mathstrutbox@\ht\z@ \dp\Mathstrutbox@\dp\z@}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$f(x+a)$ and $\mathbf{P}\left( y = (f(x)+1)^2 \right)$.
\end{document}
```

The output looks good to me (original above, mine below):

[image: nicer spacing inside brackets]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Searching for your truncated code fragment got me the linked post, and adding that "correction" made everything work completely. There was no conflict with any of the many other packages I am using. So thanks!

Comment: oh one of my answers:-)  I still think it's a bad idea even if copied from an impeccable source:-)

Comment: the space between P and ( is a well known failing of `\left\right` but addressed much more safely by the `mleftright` package

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for your feedback! It's true that meddling with internals of LaTeX is fraught with danger, but well that's precisely what my question is asking for. Heheh. =)

Answer (score 2):

Despite the comments I would use a macro here and also as seen in this example I think that line three with extra space is worse than the default layout, and I prefer the final layouts with the tighter spacing in arguments. This is all relatively subjective of course, no right and wrong.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    

\newcommand\apply[2]{#1(#2)}
\[\apply{f}{x+a} \qquad \apply{\mathbf{P}}{x=a}\]
    
\renewcommand\apply[2]{#1\left(#2\right)}
\[\apply{f}{x+a} \qquad \apply{\mathbf{P}}{x=a}\]

\renewcommand\apply[2]{#1\left(\,#2\,\right)}
\[\apply{f}{x+a} \qquad \apply{\mathbf{P}}{x=a}\]

\renewcommand\apply[2]{#1\left(\hbox{$\thinmuskip=0mu\medmuskip=0mu\thickmuskip=0mu#2$}\right)}
\[\apply{f}{x+a} \qquad \apply{\mathbf{P}}{x=a}\]

\renewcommand\apply[2]{#1\mathopen{}{\left(\hbox{$\thinmuskip=0mu\medmuskip=0mu\thickmuskip=0mu#2$}\right)}\mathclose{}}
\[\apply{f}{x+a} \qquad \apply{\mathbf{P}}{x=a}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: In my question I said extra spacing only after `(` and before `)`, so it does not look like your line 3. =) [Edit: Oh I forgot that my hack of `left` and `right` already removes the excess space before `\left(`.]

Comment: Anyway although line 4 looks nicer, it doesn't when the inner expression is a much longer one, such as `\mathbf{P}( y = (f(x)+1)^2 )`.

Comment: @user21820 yes I should probably add a line fixing up the leftright spacing of the last version to restore the \mathopen spacing

Comment: perhaps not but there are degees in between:  I set all three to 0 which might be excessively squashed:-) @user21820

Comment: @user21820 If you think this answer and/or my comments under the question will dissuade others from answering in a way you would prefer ping me and I'll delete the comments and/or this answer. (although I think this _is_ the answer:-)

Comment: I have no problem with you posting this (because you think it is the best). =) However, I will of course not upvote or accept it because it didn't address my question. =)

Comment: I just thought of something. Even if we cannot hack `(` and `)` to automatically add spacing, we can hack `\left` and `\right` to do that, right? Then at least we can have more spacing whenever we use parenthesis pairs. Do you have a way in that case?

Comment: I found a way to solve this problem by hacking `(` and `)` and `\left` and `\right`, and it works as long as I don't use `\boldsymbol`. I am guessing that this is because `\boldsymbol` attempts to handle brackets next to the bolded symbol. Is there a way to solve this `\boldsymbol` problem? I guess that it is related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46340) and/or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/483877).

Comment: @user21820 `\boldsymbol` does nothing special about brackets.

Comment: Since I have at last found what I feel is the correct answer to this question, do you mind deleting your answer? If you do, then never mind. =)

Comment: @user21820 usual thing would be for you to simply accept your answer, no harm in leaving another answer for those not wanting to risk redefining \left and \right

Comment: Yep I know that's the usual thing; I asked only because of [your comment last october](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565217/automatically-increase-spacing-inside-brackets/584196#comment1424315_565224).

Comment: yes I know but  that was when there were no other answers and I offered to encourage them, but now there is another answer (and it's somewhat dangerous to suggest to people to redefine \left) I think I'll leave this one up as an alternative but I have no complaint if you accept your own:-)

Comment: Ahh I see okay great! =)